# SQL to solve this

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following data in a table I'll call TableA:

```
ID  Status     Date
5     0        1000
20    0         900
10    1         800
30    1         700
4     1         600
8     0         500
22    1         400
1     1         300
3     0         200
```

The records are sorted by Date descendingly. I want to get only those records where Status is equal to 1 BUT only up to the first record where the Status is no longer 1. So in the sample data, records with ID: 10,30,4 would be selected but but 22 and 1 would not be because ID 8 appears and separates the sets. Preferrably the SQL should run in Sqlite. The result for this sample data should return:

```
ID  Status     Date
10     1       800
30     1       700
4      1       600
```

**EDIT**
I replaced the ID values with random values and changed the date from TEXT to Integer.

Comment: Be careful; autonumber fields in SQLite are *not* monotonic by default.

Comment: I'm not using autonumber fields.

Comment: Fair enough. But every developer using SQLite should be aware of that fact.

Comment: Your input and output data don't match... please fix!

Comment: I did fix that. Did you refresh your browser?

Comment: There's also the text about specific IDs 2,3,4 and 6,7 and 5. Could you fix those too?

Comment: Oops. Sorry about that. I think that is the final fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest

```
select * from tableA a1 where a1.status = 1 and not exists
(select 1 from tableA a2 where a2.status = 0 and a2.date > a1.date and a2.date <
(select max(date) from tableA a3 where a3.status = 1
)
)
```

Doubly nested subquery. Select rows where the status is 1 that have no rows before them with (status is 0 and that are after the earliest row where status is 1).

No idea how efficient this is.

Comment: @AndroidDev Can you clarify? In your example data there is no id 6 or 1.

Comment: I deleted that comment. Your solution returns the IDs 22 and 1

Comment: @AndroidDev Oh - you changed dates so they are descending, not ascending. Therefore I should change my suggestion.

Comment: @AndroidDev I flipped all >s to <s and vice versa and flipped all mins to maxes and vice versa. Now it will work for descending date.

Comment: Dates were always descending. I didn't change that. I only changed the data type from text to integer.

Comment: Why the downvote? If there's a problem with my query still, let me know and I can fix it.

Comment: interesting question - interesting solution.
+1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
SELECT *
FROM
   TableA A
   INNER JOIN (
      SELECT *
      FROM TableA S
      WHERE S.Status = 1
      ORDER BY S.Date DESC
      LIMIT 1
   ) S ON A.Date <= S.Date
WHERE
   A.Status = 1
   AND A.Date > (
      SELECT E.Date
      FROM TableA E
      WHERE
         E.Status = 0
         AND S.Date > E.Date
      ORDER BY Date DESC
      LIMIT 1
   )
;
```

### [See a Live Demo at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/e3ec7/1)

This should be pretty efficient because of the `LIMIT` clauses. If there are many rows in the table it theoretically won't be scanning them all--but big disclaimer: I don't work with sqlite much *at all*.

Comment: I believe it must ALWAYS scan all rows in order to correctly select the right rows. All the LIMIT does is take the first one in the list.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the information, @AndroidDev. Do you know a way around this?

Answer (score -1):

this is not tested, but will give an idea.

It's for MSSQL and uses subqueries; I dont know if it works for sqlite.

```
select RowNumber() r, *
from (select * from TableA where status = 1), (select top 1 id from TableA where status = 1) diff
where id - r = diff - 1
```

Comment: RowNumber is not a function in sqlite.